# Do I not qualify for any education tax breaks?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, tax-credit, tuition

I'm planning on going back to school for a graduate degree. Looking at the different tax breaks I could find related to education:

The American Opportunity tax credit: This is not an undergraduate degree, so this tax break does not qualify.

The Lifetime Learning Credit: My AGI is way above $52,000; so this break is out too.

The Tuition and Fees Deduction: My AGI is above $80,000 too; so I don't qualify for this either.

Student Loan Interest Deduction: If I were to take out a loan, I wouldn't even qualify for this either since my AGI is above $80,000.

So, is that the end of the road? Is there anything else I qualify for that I'm not aware of?

Comment: You could get married. Will your MAGI be as high as it is now throughout grad school?

Comment: Get married? Um, no. lol. I'm going to school part-time, so through those years I'll still be making the same as a full time employee.

Comment: See, marriage sounds even better in your scenario.  How long do you anticipate being in school? Also, is your MAGI very far above 80k?

Comment: My MAGI is too far from the $80k mark that marriage would not help either; we both would make too much still when filing jointly. To be honest, I could afford to pay for my education completely out-of-pocket, but being raised in poverty has made me an incredibly stingy person. I will still take whatever financial incentive I can get.

Comment: That's not stingy, it's prudent. Joking about marriage of course, but people have married for tax benefits, doesn't work if you'd be marrying a high-earner.  Sounds like you're out of luck, a 529 plan doesn't make sense if planning to go back immediately, and if you can't max out 401k contributions to drop MAGI below $80k then no tax breaks.

Comment: Yeah, because I'm planning on going back immediately, 529 plans make no sense since there are no tax benefits on earnings when there's no time for the earnings in the first place. Maxing out my 401(k) and HSA would not get me there either. Looks like I'm going to have to hit hard as many scholarships, grants, and whatever else the school has to offer instead. It's a nice problem to have, however. I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 2):

The Lifetime Learning Credit is $57k - $67k, single and $114k - $134k, married filing jointly. Are you married by any chance? I'm assuming, no or you would have mentioned that. Just making sure.

Best Solution (taxes be dammed) - Ask your employer to help cover some of the costs. We are at record unemployment and if you're in a field that has good job prospects you should be able to negotiate. *Every* company I have worked for over the past 13-years has offered at least $5,250 in tuition assistance per calendar year. This is a *very* common benefit at companies.

*"Under section 127 of the tax code, the IRS allows your employer to deduct the expense, and the benefit is not taxable to you as an employee."*

The limit is $5,250. I would ask for this over a bonus unless they plus-up the bonus to cover your tax portion. Even then, they are losing out on the deduction by giving you a bonus.

Spread it out over three calendar years and you're getting a large portion of that tuition paid for.

Example:

- Fall Semester, year 1
- All year, year 2
- Spring semester, year 3

This way it's closer to 2-years of real time versus 3, full years. FYSA - Some (most) employers require you to stay for one year after the end of your last course.

If not, and you're not super set on staying at that employer, leave. Then you can look for companies that offer that benefit and/or negotiate tuition assistance (or a sign-on bonus) to help cover the costs of tuition.

Other than that, yeah, welcome to higher paid employment.

Comment: My last employer offered the benefit you mention. $12,000 a year if I stay with them for another year. Because of taxes, it translated to something like $9,500 because I have to pay self-employment taxes, on top of regular income taxes on the amount in excess of the $5,250. My new employer offers the same benefit, but in the amount of $3,000, but they also increased my regular salary by $7,000; so it turns out to be almost a wash. In either case, those benefits don't even put a dent on the $100,000 tuition costs (before financial aid) of your typical MBA program.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Most of the education tax benefits are pretty paltry compared to a $100k tuition bill. For what it's worth, that sounds pretty high end, there are definitely good MBA programs for half that, so maybe you can find something agreeable for less than initially planned.

Comment: @HartCO Is $100,000 really on the high end? Out of all the schools in my area, I have only found one program that was half that. I was shocked when I found it.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Well, there are much more expensive ones as well, but the bulk seem to be in the $40k-80k range, that's based on my research last year which was not exhaustive. I checked my alma mater and their online MBA is ~$50k.

Comment: Huh. My research gave me the impression that $100,000 was the norm. I need to look more into that. Thanks.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Different topic, but I would reevaluate your $100k MBA. Unless it's an Ivy League and you plan on going to work for an investment bank or a financial/management consulting Bain Capital-like company I don't think you need a $100k MBA. To me that should be the focus, not the $2,000 tax savings on a $100k loan. What is your field of study and what do you "want" to do with your MBA?

Comment: @trying2code I'm a software engineer and want to move into the management side of things. I'm definitely not paying $100k. I was hoping that those $100k were just sticker price, and that when all was said and done, I'd end up paying for no more than half that. Are my expectations not aligned with reality?

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus - I'm IT Security. If your resume shows some managerial/leadership-type work I don't think you need an MBA. MBAs are for people that run companies not really front line "managers". Obviously if you want one, go for it, but find one that's reasonably priced. I've held Director and Manager roles that paid $200k+ and I graduated from a no name school. I quit my MBA after taking two courses because it wasn't worth it. Read two or three books on each core MBA topic then get something unique like a degree in Entrepreneurship or Management. Or an MBA if you want, just don't over pay.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus I decided to get a Masters of Science in Management with a Concentration in Entrepreneurship over the MBA. I find it more closely related to what I actually do every day. I also enjoy reading management and leadership books so I don't really look at it like school. Cheaper too. I would have read about those topics for fun anyway. The MBA on the other hand... I'll never use real accounting, marketing or value businesses in my role. It didn't seem relevant to me and not worth the inflated cost. Managing a team budget doesn't require an MBA.

Comment: @trying2code If you don't mind me asking, how old were you when you landed your director and manager roles?

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus First team lead role I was 30. First manager role I was 33 and first Director role I was 35. I just applied for three Director roles and all three places requested on-site interviews after my initial phone interview. None of them asked about an MBA or even asked about a Master degree. Neither did the other roles. All three are publicly traded companies.

Comment: @trying2code so you were making $200k+ by the age of 35? Where was this? In sillicon valley? Also, mostly startups?

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus Actually, 31 (2014). Do what you enjoy, don't chase money. It just came to me. I wasn't looking. The more money I have made the less happy I have become. Two start-ups and one very popular product company. Not Silicon Valley. Most recent is remote. I work from home (Not California or NYC). Spend less so you need to make less. Enjoy your quality of life. Constantly read books and learn new things. Btw, do you code in Python? I could use some help :)

Comment: @trying2code Not Python. For backend stuff, only C#, Java, or Rust. So do you not enjoy your job in those roles?